# Find and replace between html comment tags in dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, dreamweaver

I'm trying to get Dreamweaver to remove all content between 2 html comment tags. I have a lot of html pages in my project that have a bunch of js scripts in the bottom and they all different from page to page.

For example, let's say I have the following html:

```
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  <!-- END SCRIPTS -->
```

And I'd like to do a Find and Replace that strips everything between the comment tags and replaces it with new stuff:

```
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="new-path-for-js-files.js"></script>
  <!-- END SCRIPTS -->
```

I believe this could be possible to achieve by using regex but I couldn't find anything that would fit what I'm looking for.

I'd much appreciate your suggestions on accomplishing this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the comment tags including the content they surround by using the following `regex`:

```
<!-- SCRIPTS -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END SCRIPTS -->
```

**Explanation:**
The `regex` looks for the exact text `<!-- SCRIPTS -->` and `<!-- END SCRIPTS -->`, and tries to match all characters in between:

- `\s` is the whitespace character class (containing any whitespace character like spaces, tabs, line breaks);
- `\S` will try to match anything that is *not* in the whitespace character class
- `[\s\S]` is a character set, which tries to mach any character it contains, so in this case that means any character;
- `*` is a quantifier which tries to match 0 or more of the preceding token `[\s\S]`
- `?` is a modifier which makes the preceding quantifier lazy: by default the a quantifier like `*` is greedy and tries to match as many characters as possible, but the lazy modifier changes a quantifier so it tries to match as few characters as possible. This is necessary if you have multiple identical tags.

You said you want to replace the code *inside* the tags (so keeping the tags), which my suggested `regex` does not do (it will also match - and thus replace - the comment tags). It is possible with a `regex` using lookarounds, but that would make the `regex` more difficult; and only part of the `regex` flavors (partially) support lookarounds.
I suggest you simply add the comment tags around the replacement code if you want to keep them in the source code.

Comment: This is truly amazing I must say!!!! I was loosing my hope already lol... 
Thank you so much!!!